# Context menu for an Internet Explorer toolbar

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, toolbar, commandbar

I am working on IE toolbar and I am trying to give the command to the context menu item in web browser, means I am adding an item in context menu and then I trying to give the command for[image] that item.

i am attached the snap shot of what i need,in that snap in IE web browser when i am right click on any link the context menu was display on the screen and  if i click on XYZ i need to perform any operation...the position of xyz is also fixed on top..

Comment: Can you share what code you have so far, that'll help anybody trying to answer the question.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Can you review it and clarify exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: i have updated the question plz check and let me know if you have any solution...

Answer (score 0):

Well, a pure C# could be found [here](http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/extensibility.ph), but it  is quite a hefty price.

A workaround for creating a menu item involving the registry and JavaScript is [here](http://madhu-dotnetblog.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-add-context-menu-item-to.html).